# Does Mongoid support rails 2 anymore? Where I can find tag 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I find after Mongoid 2.0, Rails 3 is require. The last Rails 2 compatible version is 1.9.2 which have many bugs.

Question is:
1. Does Mongoid will support Rails 2?
2. Where I can find Mongoid 1.9.2 source code (There is no 1.9.2 tag on github mongoid git repo). So I can fix some bugs myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoid 1.9.2 lives in the [legacy](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/tree/legacy) git branch. Mongoid 1.9.2 is currently the most recent Mongoid version compatibile with Rails 2.

I believe they are focusing their effort on Rails 3, given that the main master branch contains Mongoid 2.0.0. Also, Mongoid makes a huge use of Rails 3 features such as ActiveModel, so I won't expect they will continue to support Rails 2 for a long time.